# Use RE to find matching of words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check if string contains specific words in a specific pattern, ignore case sensitive and ignore the order.
How can I do it in regular expression?

This is the pattern I want:

```
'word1-word2'
```

These strings should match:

```
['WORD1-word2','word2-word1']
```

These strings shouldn't match:

```
['word3-word2','word1word2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.match("word1-word2|word2-word1", "WORD1-word2", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
((?:word|WORD)[1-2]-(?:word|WORD)[1-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use anchors:

```
import re

words = ['WORD1-word2','word2-word1', 'word3-word2','word1word2']

rx = re.compile(r'^(?:word1-word2)|(?:word2-word1)$', re.I)

words_new = list(filter(lambda x: rx.search(x), words))
print(words_new)
```